# is there a way to change the walltime for currently running PBS job

Tags: pbs

I underestimated the amount of time a job would take. Would it be possible to change the time limit for a job while it is running?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
qalter jobid -l walltime=X
```

You can read the `qalter` docs [here](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/suite/8-0-1/basic/help.htm#topics/torque/commands/qalter.htm%3FTocPath%3DTORQUE%2520Resource%2520Manager%7CAppendices%7CAppendix%2520A%253A%2520Commands%2520Overview%7C_____7).

Comment: The link is broken, unfortunately. If I use this command, while the job is still queued, will this als alter PBS variables in my jobsscript that calculate a timeout time based on the walltime? In other words, is the script already executed, expect for the read PBS-options?

Comment: The link should be fixed now. Unfortunately, this cannot alter the variables that already exist inside the job process but it will make it so that the mom doesn't kill the job until the new walltime is reached.

Comment: However, in some systems, this may not work, resulting in a `qalter: Unauthorized Request` if the job has already started running. This is generally to avoid malicious users from requesting a small amount of time so they get queued quickly and then changing it to hog the resources.

If you need to correct the walltime, do so quickly, while the job is still queued.

Comment: Obviously you can overwrite the unauthorized request as root.

Comment: It not easy to get root permission.

Answer (score 3):

Yes
You can use:

```
qalter [-l resource_list] Job_ID
```

For Example:

```
qalter -l walltime=01:00:00 121214
```

Also, try to do it while the job is still queued because once it starts, this may not work & you will get a response "Unauthorized Request". Then you would need root permission to overwrite an unauthorized request.